# (batch file) open/close tab in already open browser

Tags: batch-file

Is there a possibility to just open and close one single tab in a already running chrome browser session? I dont want to start a whole new browser like the command

```
start chrome.exe http://stackoverflow.com/
```

does it. Does someone have an idea how i could realize this?

Comment: you want a blank page?

Comment: @npocmaka no, just a normal website

Answer (score 1):

I now found a way for opening a new tab on a already running browser:

```
start "webpage name" "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

But I still don't know what the command for closing a single tab in a browser is.

Answer (score 0):

Open Tab:
start "www.Discord.com"
or
start "https://Discord.com"

I still dont have any type of command that closes a tab on browser...